# Ubuntu Phones BQ discontinued: who else?

Tags: phone

I saw that BQ do not sell their ubuntu phones (Aquaris) anymore, only Android. Is there any other provider than Meizu now?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I read a Mark Shuttleworth's post ([here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/)) saying that Canonical will not invest more on the phone, so I guess that you will not find more phones.
Once they sell all their stock, I supposed it will all be finished.